# How to pass ref to a component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to pass a ref property to another component but I receive an error which I'm unable to handle.

The component which sends the ref is as bellow:

```
    import Icon from "../../Icon";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import Selectlist from "./SelectList";
import Button from "../Button";

interface IProps {
  selected?: number;
  items: any[];
  name: string;
  className?: string;
  hasSearch?: boolean;
  searchPlaceholder?: string;
  onChange: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void;
}

const Select: React.FC<IProps> = ({
  selected = 0,
  onChange,
  name,
  items,
  className,
  hasSearch = true,
  searchPlaceholder = "جستجو بین فیلترها",
}): JSX.Element => {
  const selectBtn = useRef<any>(null);
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string | null>("");
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState(items);
  const [listDirection, setListDirectiob] = useState({});

  const toggleOpen = () => {
    const elementHeight =
      selectBtn.current.offsetTop + selectBtn.current.offsetHeight + 180;

    if (elementHeight > window.innerHeight) {
      setListDirectiob({ bottom: selectBtn.current.offsetHeight });
    } else {
      setListDirectiob({ top: selectBtn.current.offsetHeight });
    }
    setData(items);
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  const closeList = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setOpen(false);
    }, 120);
  };

  const handleSelect = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setValue(e.currentTarget.textContent);
    onChange(e);
  };

  const handleSearch = (value: string) => {
    const data = items.filter((item) => {
      return item.name.includes(value);
    });

    setData(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selected && items) {
      setValue(items.find((x) => x.id === Number(selected)).name);
    }
  }, [selected, items]);

  return (
    <Button
      disabled={!items?.length}
      data-name="selectBtn"
      type="button"
      style={{ backgroundColor: !items?.length ? "#eee" : "" }}
      className={`border border-solid border-lightgray_300 rounded-md relative text-right p-XS ${className}`}
      onClick={toggleOpen}
      *ref*={selectBtn}
    >
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between flex-row-reverse">
        <span
          className={`text-sm ${value ? "black" : "text-lightgray"} font-b`}
        >
          {value || "انتخاب کنید"}
        </span>
        <Icon icon="chevron_down" className="mr-auto" />
      </div>
      <div onBlur={closeList}>
        {open && (
          <Selectlist
            listDirection={listDirection}
            items={data}
            name={name}
            hasSearch={hasSearch}
            searchPlaceholder={searchPlaceholder}
            onSelect={handleSelect}
            onSearch={(value) => handleSearch(value)}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </Button>
  );
};

export default Select;
```

I get

> Type '{ children: Element[]; disabled: boolean; "data-name": string;
> type: "button"; style: { backgroundColor: string; }; className:
> string; onClick: () => void; ref: MutableRefObject; }' is not
> assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IProps'.   Property 'ref'
> does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IProps'.

on ref property.

Would you help me please?

Comment: What does the definition for `Button` look like? Is it using [forwardRef](https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef)?

Comment: yes, I actually fixed the problem by using forwardRef.

Answer (score 0):

To pass a ref to another component in React, you need to use the `React.forwardRef`.

```
interface IProps {
 selected?: number;
 items: any[];
 name: string;
 className?: string;
 hasSearch?: boolean;
 searchPlaceholder?: string;
 onChange: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void;
 ref: ForwardedRef<any>
}

const Select: React.FC<IProps> = forwardRef({}) => {
  const selectBtn = useRef<any>(null);


<Button
    disabled={!items?.length}
    data-name="selectBtn"
    type="button"
    style={{ backgroundColor: !items?.length ? "#eee" : "" }}
    className={`border border-solid border-lightgray_300 rounded-md relative text-right p-XS ${className}`}
    onClick={toggleOpen}
    ref={(el) => {
      selectBtn.current = el;
    }}
  >
  .
  .
  .
}
```